# ESXI Crash need help to understand log and support about nexentastor on virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, server-crashes, nexenta

If i understand right, the following core dump means that the cpu4 has crashed the Host

if i read the next line it seem that at the time the CPU 4 was assigned to the NexentaStore
Vm ... SO if im right i can say that NexentaStor Vm crash my esxi

Am i right ?

Does that core dump can provide me some more informations ?

```
2012-11-14T03:48:01.046Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25ba08:[0x41803007abff]PanicvPanicInt@vmkernel#nover+0x56 stack: 0x3000000008, 0x41221f25ba
2012-11-14T03:48:01.046Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25bae8:[0x41803007b4a7]Panic@vmkernel#nover+0xae stack: 0x2e067c00000010, 0x0, 0x1f25bb38,
2012-11-14T03:48:01.047Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25bc18:[0x4180300a7823]TLBDoInvalidate@vmkernel#nover+0x45a stack: 0xca, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
2012-11-14T03:48:01.047Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25bc68:[0x418030489e17]UserMem_CartelFlush@<None>#<None>+0xce stack: 0xcaa0b, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4
2012-11-14T03:48:01.047Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25bd78:[0x41803048ab91]UserMemUnmapStateCleanup@<None>#<None>+0x58 stack: 0x0, 0x41221f25bd
2012-11-14T03:48:01.047Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25be58:[0x41803048b97d]UserMemUnmap@<None>#<None>+0x104 stack: 0x41221f267000, 0x41221f25bf
2012-11-14T03:48:01.048Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25be98:[0x41803048bf20]UserMem_Unmap@<None>#<None>+0xe3 stack: 0x426, 0x0, 0x41221f25bef8,
2012-11-14T03:48:01.048Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25beb8:[0x4180304a5985]UW64VMKSyscallUnpackReleasePhysMemMap@<None>#<None>+0x18 stack: 0x10
2012-11-14T03:48:01.048Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25bef8:[0x418030476791]User_LinuxSyscallHandler@<None>#<None>+0x17c stack: 0x41803004cc70,
2012-11-14T03:48:01.048Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25bf18:[0x4180300a82be]User_LinuxSyscallHandler@vmkernel#nover+0x19 stack: 0x3ffe63bed80, 0
2012-11-14T03:48:01.049Z cpu4:6089)0x41221f25bf28:[0x418030110064]gate_entry@vmkernel#nover+0x63 stack: 0x10b, 0x0, 0x0, 0x426, 0xcf76
2012-11-14T03:48:01.049Z cpu4:6089)VMware ESXi 5.1.0 [Releasebuild-799733 x86_64]
PCPU 1 locked up. Failed to ack TLB invalidate (total of 1 locked up, PCPU(s): 1).
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)cr0=0x80010031 cr2=0xcaa0b750 cr3=0x197d7b000 cr4=0x42768
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:0 world:6111 name:"vmm0:Windows_2012_-_SQL" (V)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:1 world:6032 name:"vmm0:Windows_2012_-_AD" (V)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:2 world:6098 name:"vmm0:Windows_2012_-_App" (V)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:3 world:4099 name:"idle3" (IS)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:4 world:6089 name:"vmx-vcpu-0:NexentaStor" (U)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:5 world:6134 name:"vmm0:Ubuntu_-_NGINX" (V)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:6 world:4102 name:"idle6" (IS)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)pcpu:7 world:4103 name:"idle7" (IS)
2012-11-14T03:48:01.050Z cpu4:6089)@BlueScreen: PCPU 1 locked up. Failed to ack TLB invalidate (total of 1 locked up, PCPU(s): 1).
```

EDIT

it has been working good since 2.5 days but crash with an error

```
2012-11-16T16:15:35.233Z cpu6:4102)World: 8381: PRDA 0x418041800000 ss 0x0 ds 0x4018 es 0x4018 fs 0x4018 gs 0x4018
2012-11-16T16:15:35.233Z cpu6:4102)World: 8383: TR 0x4020 GDT 0x4122001a1000 (0x402f) IDT 0x41800b112000 (0xfff)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.233Z cpu6:4102)World: 8384: CR0 0x80010031 CR3 0x125f24000 CR4 0x42768
2012-11-16T16:15:35.238Z cpu6:4102)Backtrace for current CPU #6, worldID=4102, ebp=0x41220019bc10
2012-11-16T16:15:35.239Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bc10:[0x41800b052105]IRQ_DoInterrupt@vmkernel#nover+0x5c stack: 0x0, 0x418041800180, 0x0,
2012-11-16T16:15:35.239Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bc50:[0x41800b04bd92]IDT_IntrHandler@vmkernel#nover+0x139 stack: 0x41220019bd68, 0x41800b
2012-11-16T16:15:35.239Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bc60:[0x41800b110064]gate_entry@vmkernel#nover+0x63 stack: 0x4018, 0x4018, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
2012-11-16T16:15:35.240Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bd68:[0x41800b2dbd6f]Power_HaltPCPU@vmkernel#nover+0x276 stack: 0x41220019be68, 0x4122001
2012-11-16T16:15:35.240Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019be68:[0x41800b1bd114]CpuSchedIdleLoopInt@vmkernel#nover+0x873 stack: 0x41220019be98, 0x41
2012-11-16T16:15:35.240Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019be78:[0x41800b1c66ae]CpuSched_IdleLoop@vmkernel#nover+0x15 stack: 0x6, 0x6, 0x41220019bfe
2012-11-16T16:15:35.241Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019be98:[0x41800b04f6ce]Init_SlaveIdle@vmkernel#nover+0x49 stack: 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
2012-11-16T16:15:35.241Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bfe8:[0x41800b2e1f86]SMPSlaveIdle@vmkernel#nover+0x31d stack: 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
2012-11-16T16:15:35.241Z cpu6:4102)VMware ESXi 5.1.0 [Releasebuild-799733 x86_64]
#PF Exception 14 in world 4102:idle6 IP 0x41800b052105 addr 0x417fd1837b01
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)cr0=0x8001003d cr2=0x417fd1837b01 cr3=0xcdff6000 cr4=0x216c
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)frame=0x41220019bae0 ip=0x41800b052105 err=0 rflags=0x10006
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)rax=0x66f1400 rbx=0x41220019bc50 rcx=0x41800b2dbd6f
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)rdx=0x417fcb146700 rbp=0x41220019bc10 rsi=0x41220019bc70
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)rdi=0x19bc50 r8=0x4100018d29b0 r9=0x4ca88b
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)r10=0xdf r11=0x1 r12=0x4122001a7000
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)r13=0x19bc50 r14=0x41220019bc70 r15=0x1
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:0 world:6211 name:"vmm1:Windows_2012_-_SQL" (V)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:1 world:4109 name:"directMapUnmap" (S)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:2 world:6255 name:"vmm0:NexentaStor" (V)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:3 world:6194 name:"vmm0:Windows_2012_-_App" (V)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:4 world:6207 name:"vmm0:Windows_2012_-_SQL" (V)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:5 world:5855 name:"vmm0:Windows_2012_-_AD" (V)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:6 world:4102 name:"idle6" (IS)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)pcpu:7 world:4103 name:"idle7" (IS)
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)@BlueScreen: #PF Exception 14 in world 4102:idle6 IP 0x41800b052105 addr 0x417fd1837b01
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)Code start: 0x41800b000000 VMK uptime: 2:11:18:25.729
2012-11-16T16:15:35.242Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bc10:[0x41800b052105]IRQ_DoInterrupt@vmkernel#nover+0x5c stack: 0x0
2012-11-16T16:15:35.243Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bc50:[0x41800b04bd92]IDT_IntrHandler@vmkernel#nover+0x139 stack: 0x41220019bd68
2012-11-16T16:15:35.243Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bc60:[0x41800b110064]gate_entry@vmkernel#nover+0x63 stack: 0x4018
2012-11-16T16:15:35.244Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bd68:[0x41800b2dbd6f]Power_HaltPCPU@vmkernel#nover+0x276 stack: 0x41220019be68
2012-11-16T16:15:35.244Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019be68:[0x41800b1bd114]CpuSchedIdleLoopInt@vmkernel#nover+0x873 stack: 0x41220019be98
2012-11-16T16:15:35.244Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019be78:[0x41800b1c66ae]CpuSched_IdleLoop@vmkernel#nover+0x15 stack: 0x6
2012-11-16T16:15:35.245Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019be98:[0x41800b04f6ce]Init_SlaveIdle@vmkernel#nover+0x49 stack: 0x0
2012-11-16T16:15:35.245Z cpu6:4102)0x41220019bfe8:[0x41800b2e1f86]SMPSlaveIdle@vmkernel#nover+0x31d stack: 0x0
2012-11-16T16:15:35.247Z cpu6:4102)base fs=0x0 gs=0x418041800000 Kgs=0x0
2012-11-16T16:15:35.247Z cpu6:4102)vmkernel             0x0 .data 0x0 .bss 0x0
```

Is that related to previous one or just another host instability

Comment: Hi mate, what type of metal are you running on? Is it HP? Do you have energy saving options turned on in your host bios (you shouldn't). Is it running win 2012 (its not supported at the mo, so make sure you have all the latest patches installed.

Comment: i have ESXI 5.1 so it seem that Windows 2012 is supported

Comment: btw i use it with \Bios mode not EFI, don't know if that could be an issue

Comment: yea I heard it works, but I meant I don't think it is "officially supported" I'll cheek though. I'm fairly sure it is meant to use EFI boot however (this is a check bo in the settings)

Comment: win2k12 is supported on 5.1 I was wrong there. Just had a hunch but am probably wrong, do you have any power management options turned on in the bios at all?

Comment: most issue fixed after disabling power management in bios ... but i haven't be able to have a stable esxi, some crash with datastore, hdd fails randomly ... i think that esxi really require entreprise hardware..

Comment: Im not sure if enterprise hardware is required (although it is a good idea if you can get it). You HDD fail and probably your datastore have nothing to do with esx, it sounds like you have storage problems. Check /var/log/vmkernel.log for storage errors. @Tims answer is probably correct given your last comment

Comment: Most "consumer" grade disks are practically garbage. You will want SSD or Enterprise storage. ESXi does not handle "blips" with disks well like a desktop OS. Most desktops ignore the blip and move on. ESXi likes to halt and ham it up.

Answer (score 1):

VMware article on debugging "Failed to ack TLB" purple screens:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1020214

It sounds like hardware, you may need a VMware tech to investigate.